# how can select a parent tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a code like below:

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="">
   <div id="navContainer">
       <div id="active">
           [ some list ]
       </div><!-- #active -->
   </div><!-- #navContainer -->
</nav><!-- #mainNav -->
```

i want to change the background color of #mainNav when user hover on #active, but i dont know what to do. i did this and no results:

```
#active:hover #mainNav{
   background-color: #333;
}
```

any idea?

Comment: You can't, there's no parent selector :(

Comment: This can only be done with JavaScript.

Comment: no way? even javascript?

Comment: what would you like to do?

Comment: yes can use jquery, but css in priority

Comment: if you want to do it without js/jQuery, take a look at my answer

Comment: OMG, stop solving everything with jQuery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JS or try a different approach, **CSS ONLY**:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/zxybD/5/

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <a href="#" class="red">red</a>
    <a href="#" class="green">green</a>
    <a href="#" class="blue">blue</a>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
    position: relative;
}

#main > a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em;
}

#main > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: -1;
}

#main > a.red:hover ~ div {
    background-color: red;
}

#main > a.green:hover ~ div {
    background-color: green;
}

#main > a.blue:hover ~ div {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: oh good idea coma :)
simple and creative

Answer (score 1):

As One Trick Pony commented, there is no parent selector in pure CSS (at least yet).  If you want to select the parent, you'd have to do so either through a different kind of selector (which requires knowledge of the DOM structure), or through something like Javascript.

In Javascript you can use `.parentNode` on the element to get its parent.  If you have jQuery, you can call `.parent()`.

Comment: different kind of selector? Please explain more

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#active").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#mainNav").css("background-color", "#333");
});
```

Don't forget to change it on mouse leaving as well.

```
$("#active").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#mainNav").css("background-color", "#ABC" /*some other color*/);
});
```

Comment: Do you see a jQuery tag anywhere? Besides, `.hover()` would be a far better choice.

Comment: @Kolink check the OP's comments in the question. He accepts CSS answers.

Comment: Fair enough, but the point about `.hover` still stands ;)

Comment: I agree. .Hover would be better. Editing.

Comment: .hover would assign the same function to two different events. I've broken it down into two parts as per the jQuery specs.

Comment: Um... `.hover` lets you define separate functions, unless I'm much mistaken.

Comment: Just checked and yeah, it does. My bad. I think the example is (just slightly) more readable, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way to have a CSS parent selector i would suggest you rethink your design.

add the class name `active` to the parent div when there is the div with id="active" as a child and you style the .active class to your needs:

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="{if child active print 'active'}">
   <div id="navContainer">
       <div id="active">
           [ some list ]
       </div><!-- #active -->
   </div><!-- #navContainer -->
</nav><!-- #mainNav -->
```

Depending on the language you are using you can accomplish this.

```
#mainNav.active:hover #active{
   ... your hover properties ...
}
```

Comment: How exactly would this help? OP wants the style to change when a child is hovered over...

Comment: See my edit, i added an example

Comment: Still, that would apply the different colour no matter where in the navbar the mouse is hovering...

Comment: actually it will only apply to the id active

Answer (score 1):

CSS4 defines a "subject" operator, which would allow you to do this:

```
!#mainNav #active:hover { background-color:#333 }
```

However, as far as I am aware no browsers support this yet. Instead, you can use this JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('mainNav'), active = document.getElementById('active'),
        f = function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            nav.style.backgroundColor = e.type.match(/mouseover/) ? "#333" : "";
        };
    if( window.addEventListener) {
        active.addEventListener("mouseover",f,false);
        active.addEventListener("mouseout",f,false);
    }
    else {
        active.attachEvent("onmouseover",f);
        active.attachEvent("onmouseout",f);
    }
})();
```

Comment: I thought the `!` was intended to *follow* the subject (`#mainNav!`, though there's been quite some discussion about preceding, following and/or wrapping in that regard)? And, incidentally, things seem to be changing (so far as CSS is concerned, at least) again: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#profiles

Comment: @DavidThomas The example showed it prefixed, and the note seems to mention something about it changing and being undecided XD

Comment: The link was only to illustrate the fact that the subject selector isn't implemented in the 'fast' profile and "CSS implementations conformant to Selectors Level 4 must use the 'fast' profile for CSS selection." As to the syntax, yeah: honestly, I probably shouldn't have mentioned that, given the state of flux.